# Can you use 'about' with 'tickled pink' (tickled pink about)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms

Can you say you are *tickled pink **about**  something* the same way as you can say you *are **happy** about something*?

> 1. I wasn't tickled pink about being invited but I went regardless.
> 2. I wasn't happy about being invited but I went regardless.

I haven't seen that preposition used with that idiom, it always seems to be followed by either 'by' or 'with'.

Comment: Use it wherever you would use _happy._ Because it's a participle and not an adjective, it's even better than _happy,_ because you can't be _happy by that gift,_ but you can be _tickled pink by/about/with/over that gift!_

Comment: [*tickled pink*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tickled+pink)

Comment: It should be noted that this idiom is more common in different regions. Of course it can be used anywhere, but when I hear the phrase, "tickled pink" I definitely think of the "South."

Answer (score 2):

> tickled pick
>   *very happy*

is an idiom and superlative which means very "happy", possibly giddy, and is usually used in a positive sense.

> She was *tickled pink* to be admitted to the college of her choice.

the opposite would be

> not very happy
>   not too happy

where a superlative is used to modify "happy".

Some prepositions which can be used used with "tickled pick"

> tickled pink about
>   tickled pink with
>   tickled pink by

Answer (score 0):

**Tickled pink** means being very much **pleased** or **entertained**. For example:

> I was tickled pink to have you visit us.
>
> We were tickled pink when your flowers arrived.

**OR**

> I was happy to have you visit us.
>
> We were happy when your flowers arrived.

As **happy** (being pleased) means the same.

So they are interchangeable.